# (obj == null) vs (null == obj)?

Tags: java, oop, comparison

My boss said I should use `null == obj`, because it's better than `obj == null`, but he didn't remember why to do this. Is there any reason for using `null == obj`?
I feel it somehow... opposite!

After some search on Google, the only thing I found is:

> in C, it prevents you accidentally from typing (obj = null) in a conditional structure.

Comment: The only thing I was aware of is the thing you found on Google. This is probably your boss being conditioned by C programming. That being said, I wouldn't fight it.

Comment: I think that this idea is a hold-over from C.

Comment: Definitely a C thing. I wouldn't go for it personally, since it reads completely backwards.

Comment: So... it's useless and non-natural in Java? I don't mean only performance benefits, just any benefits (null == obj) may give? I'm hoping there will be a better answer, so if there's no better answer tomorrow, I will mark Femaref's answer.

Comment: I'm reading this question in 2020 and I would like to say that  "null == obj" tickles my brain every time I see it, and it is also the reason why I came to this page. It seems unnatural, and for that reason, I would say that writing "null == obj" is less productive than "obj == null" because it annoys the majority of future developers/maintainers of your code. Of course, you can get used to something, but if it is unnecessary then you don't have to.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't accidently assign `null` to `obj` by typing `obj = null` instead. However, that's a reminiscence from C times, in java, it is not possible, as the `=` expression returns the right hand side of the assignment. As `null` is not a `boolean`, the compiler will complain.

I would try to explain it to my boss once, demonstrate it. If he still doesn't agree with you, just do it. It's a petty thing to fight about with your boss.

Comment: In general that statement is true, but with one exception: If `obj` is a `Boolean`, then `if (obj = null)` will not trigger a compiler error

Comment: On the Google result, he (she) explained: `In C it is possible to write if (obj = null) . . . by mistake (when you intended to write == null) and you get two errors for the price of one:
The object reference is set to null
The condition after the if becomes false implicitly`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Boolean is an object type, it cant be set to null

Comment: @Dani: of course you can set a `Boolean` variable to null. Why not? `Boolean flag; flag = null;` and therefor `if (flag = null)` will compile without a problem.

Comment: @Dani: Aren't you mixing things up? Primitive types are the ones that can't be null, Boolean objects (the boxed type, not the primitive) can for sure be null.

Comment: @a_horse `if(flag=null)` will give an error because `flag=null` is not a boolean expression and thus cannot be used in a conditional

Comment: @ratchet freak: try it with flag being defined as `Boolean` :)

Answer (score 25):

If you compile your file with `if(null==obj)`, the generated byte code is `if_acmpne` and in case of `if(obj==null)` it is `ifnonnull`. Now in `if_acmpne` two operands are popped out of stack and checked they are not equal(in this case `null` and `obj`), and in `ifnonnull`, only one operand is popped and checked if it is not null. From this it seems `ifnonnull` is better as it involves popping of only one operand.

References : http://www.artima.com/underthehood/flowP.html

Answer (score 17):

In Java, there is no difference.

I prefer (obj==null) since it feels more natural.

Comment: Not really an answer, you should make it a comment next time.

Comment: @XcodeDev it's a fairly simple question in fairness, unless a load of tangential information about compiler specifics is required?

Comment: @XcodeDev: It's a perfect answer. Especially considering that the entire question was "(obj == null) vs (null == obj)?", which has a pretty vague scope.

Answer (score 2):

If you do pass a condition as such `if (obj=null)` or `if (null=obj)` in present day java IDE's, it will highlight it as syntax error, In addition - attempt to compile will signal the error.

Both `(obj==null)` and `(null==obj)` are acceptable, they both carry the same overhead, the later do not yield any performance whatsoever. Decision to using either depends on code style adopted to maintain uniform style across classes.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of this before, but it seems like the reasoning you gave is solid. I also think it feels backwards but, it should not have any issues other than "feeling" wrong. I don't think it would have any performance benefits or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

:)

One thing I've found useful about this is that the below syntax (absolutely valid from my POV) is not causing `spotbugs`' `DC-DOUBLECHECK` warning, allowing to raise `spotbugs` threshold without any special exclusion etc:

```
if (defaultClient == null) {
    synchronized (DEFAULT_CLIENT_INIT_LOCK) {
        if (null == defaultClient) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```