# Eclipse generating equals method: if ( obj == null ) vs. if ( null == obj )

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, equals

Eclipse likes to generate `equals` methods (for classes having no super class) with a `null`check like this:

```
if ( null == obj )
    return false;
```

However, I like

```
if ( obj == null )
    return false;
```

much more, because it is more readable. (It kind of disturbs me all the time.)

**Q:**

Why does Eclipse generate it with `null` coming before `obj`, given that the `if ( null == obj )` is an obsolete practice stemming from C/C++ as described here?:

[(obj == null) vs (null == obj)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883646/obj-null-vs-null-obj)

Are there any (runtime) differences between the two? I can only speculate...

---

**Update:**

Eclipse Kepler seems to generate `if ( obj == null )`, so this applies to former Eclipse versions only.

Class before:

```
public class Burp
{
    private Long id ;

    public Burp()
    {
        // test
    }
}
```

Class after:

```
public class Burp
{
    private Long id ;

    public Burp()
    {
        // test
    }

    // hashCode() omitted

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj )
    {
        if ( this == obj )
            return true;
        if ( obj == null )
            return false;
        if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() )
            return false;
        Burp other = ( Burp ) obj;
        if ( this.id == null )
        {
            if ( other.id != null )
                return false;
        }
        else if ( !this.id.equals( other.id ) )
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think we have some cleaning up to do for our pre-Kepler generated `equals` methods.

Comment: `if ( obj = null )` yields an error in Eclipse and any correct Java compiler.

Comment: You may end up with the answer "It had to be one way round and what you consider more readable isn't necessarily what everyone considers more readable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference and the convention in Java (if we assume that the JDK is a reference) is to use `if (obj == null)`. See for example the code of `Objects#requireNonNull`:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    return obj;
}
```

For what it's worth, Netbeans auto-generates `equals` with `if (obj == null) return false;`.

Whichever you use won't make a difference at runtime and will generate the same bytecode.

Answer (score 4):

Some people write `null == obj` instead `obj == null`, because there is no risk to type `=` instead of `==`, but it doesn't change how your code works. Keep in mind that in Java it's only possible to write `obj = null` (without an error) when obj is `Boolean`. This way of writing code comes from other programming languages like C where it's completely valid to write `obj = null` by mistake.

Comment: If Eclipse generates this kind of code, why should "typing" be an argument?

Comment: Guess whoever wrote the template typed it that way?

Comment: Good point. People read from left to right, and i can devine what will follow after `if (null == ` much more than what will follow after `if (obj == `.

Comment: @assylias you're correct it can't be called convention, I've removed that. Some people just think it's a good practice.

Comment: `if ( obj = null )` yields an error in Eclipse and any correct Java compiler.

Comment: For example if your obj is Boolean there is no error! Btw why 2 down votes?

Comment: The argument to type `if ( obj = null )` is no danger because a Java compiler (Eclipse) will catch it, see my comment above yours.

Comment: Type this `Boolean a = true; if(a = null) {}` in your compiler and you'll see that's possible.

Comment: Yes, but do you generate `equals` methods for the `Boolean` class?

Comment: I'm just saying it's possible in Java in general and why people use it. In case of equals method it's not possible to make such mistake, so null == obj was generated, because author of this template probably writes his code that way every time in every class and method. This style of writing besides readability doesn't have any other disadvantages, but I prefer to write obj == null.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the template for generating equals method in Eclipse, refer the following [link](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/visual-guide-templates-eclipse)

As far as Runtime differences between the two are concerned I think both the expressions should be the same as the compiler would optimize both the null check expressions in a similar way (i.e same bytecode will be generated). Its more about what conventions people like to use , and it varies from person to person.

Answer (score 1):

also some people like Master **Yoda style** where you compare constant and then varible

if (5 == i) -- Yoda style