# Java: If statement not working?

Tags: java

*Awnsers below worked, thanks guys!*

```
boolean Again = true;
while (Again = true) 
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input Za Number");
    try 
    {
        int input2 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        int R1 = 1;
        int R2 = 1;
        while (R2 < input2)
        {
            R1 = R1 * 2;
            R2 = R2 + 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, R1);
        }
        String Ag = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Do it again? (Y/N)");
        if (Ag.equals("N"))
        {
            Again = false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "What is  '" + input + "'?!?! Enter an actual number.");  
    }
}
```

I put the part thats not working as I hope in bold. Its the "if (Ag.equals("N"))". Im trying to make it so if a user inputs "N", then the program will stop running. Otherwise it will loop and keep going. Problem is, even if I type N, it will loop. I am getting no errors. Please help, I am much confuse :(

Comment: `while (Again = true) ` must be `while (Again == true) ` (or simply `while (Again)`)

Comment: Thanks Andreas, your solution fixed it :D

Comment: In the end, you are victim of bad practices. Simply avoid `someBool == true` (or false). Just do `if (someBool)` or while, or ... Besides: read about naming conventions - variable names start with lower case letters. And: give the things you are using **meaningful** names: "input2" means nothing. R1 means nothing. R2 means nothing.

Answer (score 4):

This is a prime example as to why *professional* developers will always use

```
if ( null == object )
```

over

```
if ( object == null )
```

In the event of a mistype, such as the following

```
// as posted
while ( Again = true ) // works, always true

// the other way
while ( true = Again ) // compiler error
```

the way as posted would be reassigning the value *true* to *Again* every time the loop is reiterated; if the statement had been written the other way, the compiler would have thrown an error, stating that you can not assign a value to *true*.

With just the single equals, you are reassigning the value of *Again* to *true* every time you get here, where as the double equals checks for equality.

In a case such as this, you really don't even need the `true`, you could simply be using

```
while ( Again )
// or again
while ( true == Again )
```

[relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6883646/1790644)

Answer (score 2):

When you do something like

```
while (Again = true)
```

you are actually assigning the variable to `true`,

**that is making your while infinite**...

---

Do instead

```
 while (Again)  // since is boolean you dont need to compare against a true value..
```