# Way to check if a thread is null or not (in Java), does operand position makes difference

Tags: java, android, if-statement, nullpointerexception, null

**NOTE:** I went through these but didn't get my answer [Best way to check for null values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302256/best-way-to-check-for-null-values-in-java/40777583) and [(obj == null) vs (null == obj)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883646/obj-null-vs-null-obj)

I was studying this Android [Java] official documentation on Background Tasks -> Run code on a thread pool thread -> [Interrupt running code](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code#StopThread), and the null check code in the sample is:

```
if (null != thread) {
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

which is  different from what we usually see/use:

```
if (object != null) {
    //do something;
}
```

So, my question is that:

Does it make any difference (like helping avoid null pointer or something) if we write "null != thread" instead of "thread != null" or Google Official documentation is just randomly swapping the operands without any benefit?

**EDIT:**

1. I am asking about **!=** and not **==**. In case of **==**, the programmer may
   do assignment(**=**) instead of comparison(**==**). But that is not the case
   in **!=**.
2. I am talking about **Java** and not **C language**. So, that **assignment** and
   **comparison** confusion doesn't apply here.

Comment: this is a very strange observation and also a quite odd question :) but i don't think there's any difference.

Comment: Note that `==` and `!=` are symmetric relations, so order does not make any difference.

Comment: @a_local_nobody actually, when I read a program which is written by a better (my presumption since author works for google here) programmer, and I see any different style of coding, I wonder that I maybe doing it wrong...

Comment: @GyroGearless that is probably worth an answer :D

Comment: Also note that the usage `null != foo` is sometimes preferred by seasoned C programmers, where it was easy to a accidentally write `foo=null` (an assignment) instead of `foo==null` (an comparison). There is no strict reason to do the same in java.

Comment: @GyroGearless Actually, I thought that it might make a difference in preventing NullPointException in some cases, since condition evalution process in Java is always left to right...

Comment: @GyroGearless ya, I read about that "accidental assignment" instead of "comparison" thing in the other answer.

Comment: @Oo.oO Hmmm... maybe that is the programmer's (author of the above documentation) pattern of writing.

Comment: @OleV.V. Good point to note. Thanks

Comment: There are so many good answer to the linked original question. You’ll learn much more from reading those than from reading the correct and helpful comment by @GyroGearless turned into an answer here. I think that closing as a duplicate was meant to help you. Do you think that asking about `!=` makes it a (very) different question from the one about `==`?

Comment: I understand that there are good answers there. But, I think it makes difference because for ==, most answer only talk about accidental assignment instead of comparison.

Comment: For the record, this question was previusly closed as a duplicate of [(obj == null) vs (null == obj)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883646/obj-null-vs-null-obj). It has been reopened after a request from the questioner since the core of the explanation for `==` doesn’t make much sense for `!=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No semantic difference

```
if (null != thread) {
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

Why the otherwise bright folks at Google wrote the null check in this backward way remains guesswork. I agree with you that it is harder to read than the natural `thread != null`.

There is no gain whatsoever from the backward writing. The semantics are exactly the same.

Backward writing of an `if` condition is known as a *Yoda condition*. Yoda conditions are debated, some say they have their place in some programming languages (like C) under some circumstances. In case of `==` rather than `!=` for comparison you can read some of the arguments in the previously linked duplicate (I repeat the link at the bottom). In Java one might have a sought-after argument in a case like the following:

```
boolean b;
if (b == false) {
    // Do something
}
```

Imagine that a programmer coming from Pascal or another programming language that uses single `=` for comparison and putting single `=` here by mistake. It would change the meaning to assigning `false` to `b` and never executing the conditional code. So the argument goes that by writing `false == b` the compiler will catch such a mistake for you, which is a clear advantage. However:

1. Most compilers and IDEs do catch the mistake anyway. For example if I put a single `=` in the above `if` statement, my Eclipse says

   > Possible accidental assignment in place of a comparison. A condition
   >   expression should not be reduced to an assignment
2. The `if` statement would usually be written in the following way, which excludes any meaningful debate about a Yoda condition and is also generally recommended:

   ```
   if (! b) {
       // Do something
   }
   ```

So going back to your question my guess is: A programmer at Google had the habit of writing Yoda conditions like `null == thread` and by false analogy extended it to `null != thread` too.

### So does the order of != operands never carry any semantics?

For the sake of completeness, when I say that `thread != null` and `null != thread` have the same semantics, I am talking about this quoted code. In case of for example `someObj.foo() != anotherObj.bar()` the order imposes an order of the two method calls. If both methods have side effects that interfere somehow, the order of applying those side effects may make a difference in some cases.

### Links

- [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) on Wikipedia
- [(obj == null) vs (null == obj)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883646/obj-null-vs-null-obj) (of which question your question here was previously deemed a duplicate)